# how add a new field to all existing documents using spring mongo

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mongodb, spring-mongo

is there any way to add a new field to all existing documents using spring  mongo.

looking for something similar to

db.collection.update({"all_document"},

```
               {$set:{"payment_status":false}

               });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to achieve this. You can update all the existing documents command with [update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/index.html) or [updateMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/).

```
db.collection.update({},{ $set : { "new_field" : [UPDATE_VALUE] } },{ upsert : false, multi : true } ) 

db.collection.updateMany({},  { $set: { "new_field" : 'value' } });
```

[Example](https://play.db-ai.co/m/XrfH7oOtowABypET)